# Only return @@ROWCOUNT of 1 update command from stored procedure with multiple update commands

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, dapper

I have a stored procedure that executes multiple insert statements that are related, but I only want to return the count of the rows inserted into the dbo.UserTags table.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.UserTag(Tag)
    SELECT DISTINCT Tag 
    FROM @UsersTagsWorking
    WHERE Tag NOT IN (SELECT Tag FROM dbo.UserTag)

INSERT INTO dbo.UserUserTag(UserID, UserTagID)
    SELECT DISTINCT T.UserID, U.TagID 
    FROM @UsersTagsWorking T
    INNER JOIN dbo.UserTag U ON U.Tag = T.Tag
    WHERE T.UserID NOT IN (SELECT UserID FROM DBO.UserUserTag)
```

I am using Dapper's `ExecuteAsync` method to execute the stored procedure.

```
connection.ExecuteAsync("dbo.usp_InsertUsersTags", param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

`param` is created using a SQL user defined field.

```
var param = new
{
    usersTags = usersTagsDT.AsTableValuedParameter("UsersTagsUDT")                    
};
```

Is there any way to achieve this with `Execute`/`ExecuteAsync` or would I have to change to something like `Query` and then just return the count by storing `@@ROWCOUNT` in a variable

```
SELECT @InsertedTagCount = @@ROWCOUNT
```

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest that you assign the value of `@@ROWCOUNT` after your `INSERT` to  `dbo.UserTag` to an output parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All credit goes to @Larnu for his suggestion in the comment.

To close the loop, here is the solution.

Stored procedure declaration

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InsertUsersTags]
(
    @UsersTags UsersTagsUDT READONLY,
    @InsertedTagCount INT OUTPUT
)
```

Populate OUTPUT variable

```
INSERT INTO dbo.UserTag(Tag)
SELECT DISTINCT Tag FROM @UsersTagsWorking
WHERE Tag NOT IN (SELECT Tag FROM dbo.UserTag)

SELECT @InsertedTagCount = @@ROWCOUNT   

INSERT INTO dbo.UserUserTag(UserID, UserTagID)
SELECT DISTINCT T.UserID, U.TagID FROM @UsersTagsWorking T
INNER JOIN dbo.UserTag U ON U.Tag = T.Tag
WHERE T.UserID NOT IN (SELECT UserID FROM DBO.UserUserTag)
```

C# Dapper code

```
var param = new DynamicParameters();
param.Add("@InsertedTagCount", 0, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);
param.Add("@UsersTags", usersTagsDT.AsTableValuedParameter("UsersTagsUDT"));
                
await connection.ExecuteAsync("dbo.usp_InsertUsersTags", param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

int insertedTagCount = param.Get<int>("@InsertedTagCount");

return insertedTagCount;
```